# Joint Random Variable: Given f(x,y), find P(X>Y)

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

There are 2 continuous random variables, X and Y.

Say the joint pdf of (X,Y) is f(x,y).

How do you find the P(X>Y) generally? Like I am not sure where to start with.

Answer (score 2):

You must calculate
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left[\int_y^{+\infty}f(x,y)dx\right]dy$$
or
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left[\int_{-\infty}^xf(x,y)dy\right]dx$$

which yeld the same result.

Comment: is there a way to visualise or reason about this? because I don't quite understand the concept of playing around with the limits of the integrals in order to solve the problem. cheers

Answer (score 2):

So we have $P(X>Y) = P(X-Y>0) = P ((X,Y) \in C)$

Where $C = \{(x,y):x-y>0\}$

But we know how to find this, as this is the same as simply evaluating f(x,y) and integrating this over the region C.

$P(X>Y) = \iint_C f(x,y) dxdy$ .

Comment: so with that said, if the question now, say changed to find P(4Y > 3X), does that mean I should bound f(x,y) like the following?

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{4y/3}f(x,y)dx\right]dy$$

and if so, what about P(X=Y) ?

Comment: Yes. Personally I wouldn't stick to a general formula, just define the region where you want (X,Y) to lie and you should be able to see what the integral should be. Well what region C would X=Y correspond to?